# React App - примеры профессионального кода

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте, работаю над проектом с использованием React. Проект начал делать 2 месяца назад - после недели знакомства с React. Все далось достаточно легко.
Проект достаточно большой и вроде бы все работает нормально, но не покидает ощущение, что-то нужно менять...

Может-ли кто-нибудь дать ссылку на источник, где можно посмотреть пример хорошего кода полноценного проекта, который успешно используется где-то. Чтобы я мог свой проект подогнать под какие-то рамки и жить дальше без мысли о том, что мое приложение когда-нибудь развалится из-за какой-то мелочи, которую я не учел будучи не профи.

Comment: Уточни стек технологий, который ты используешь в своем проекте.

Comment: @CoonJS  пока что хватает Redux и Redux-Saga, так же много запросов к API с использованием библиотеки coreapi - ее поменять не получится, но пример того как более структурировано и удобно организовать API запросы не помещает