# Примеры хорошего кода React

Tags: reactjs

В каких источниках можно посмотреть свежий код (в пределах года) приложений React на JS и TS от опытных разработчиков? Хочется сравнить свой код с их и что-то для себя вынести. Попытки гугления особо много результатов не дали. Не особо имеет значение Redux/Mobx и прочее.

Comment: Github? [6 символов]

Comment: Чёрт, вот только недавно закрывали почти такой же вопрос, видимо Дух удалил его. Может закроем как дубликат к этому https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808806/react-app-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0 ?

Comment: В той теме нет ответа на вопрос, на гитхабе выдает что угодно, кроме нормальных проектов на реакте.